# How do I trigger a firebase cloud function only when a field is updated?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to trigger a cloud function only when a particular field of a firestore document is updated. I don't want to trigger it every time the document is updated regardless which field. Is it possible?

For example:

```
exports.onAvatarUpdated = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/avatarUrl')
  .onUpdate(change => { 
  // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently there are no triggers for a specific field.  You can only trigger on any change to a document, and if you want to know if a particular field changed, you have to examine the change object to figure it out.

You can always [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) if you would like to be able to express a function that only pays attention to particular field.

Comment: @Curse No, and I suspect it's not likely to happen.

Comment: it's possible with firebase db trigger, isn't firestore supposed to be an "improvement" of firebase db?

Comment: @Curse The way data is modeled is fundamentally different between the two databases.  If you need to trigger on a single field, you can always make a single document with a single field, and put everything else in a separate document. This is a valid data design decision. A document doesn't have to be the sole source of data for a given entity.

Answer (score 5):

I will change Firebase native manual code from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events):

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
  // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const newFieldValue = newValue.field;

  // ...or the previous value before this update
  const previousValue = change.before.data();
  const previousFieldValue = previousValue.field;


  if (previousFieldValue!== newFieldValue) 
       {      // perform desired operations ... }
});
```